# Connect to teradata using DBI Package in R

Tags: r, teradata, dbi

Can you anyone help me with how to connect to Teradata using DBI ODBC Package?

I use the code below,

```
  con <- dbConnect( drv = dbDriver('Teradata'),
                   server=prodServer,
                   DBCName=prodDatabaseName,
                   uid=username,
                   pwd=password,
                   MechanismName = TD2)
```

but it throws the following error:

```
Error: Couldn't find driver Teradata. Looked in:
* global namespace
* in package called Teradata
* in package called RTeradata
```

Comment: Do you have a Teradata ODBC driver installed? If so, which version? The driver name 'Teradata' applies to 15.10 and earlier; later versions have driver names like 'Teradata Database ODBC Driver _xx.yy_'.  There is also an R DBI module for Teradata available.

Comment: @Fred, I tried using Driver name as 'Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10' as my version is 16.10. However I receive another error as below: Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 08001: [WSock32 DLL] 10065 WSA E HostUnreach: The Teradata server can't currently be reached over this network

Comment: Then either the name you supplied isn't resolving to the correct address, or Windows can't figure out how to connect to that address. Some things you can try to help isolate the problem: **nslookup prodDatabaseNameCOP1** and **nslookup prodDatabaseName** and/or specify an _IP address_ for `DBCName`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Teradata ODBC driver, DBCName is a network name (which for other drivers would typically supplied as Server)

```
  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
               Driver = DRIVER,
               DBCName = SERVER,
               Database = defaultDatabase,
               UID = Sys.getenv("tera_user"), 
               PWD = Sys.getenv("tera_pass"))
```

After quite a looot of research, I finally found this in an answer by @Fred to another question:

[R-Studio - connection to Teradata is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413061/r-studio-connection-to-teradata-is-not-working)