# R-Studio - connection to Teradata is not working

Tags: rstudio, teradata

I have got the issue when trying to connect my R-studio to Teradata. It gives me

`Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 08001: [Teradata][WSock32 DLL] (439) WSA E HostUnreach: The Teradata server can't currently be reached over this network`

however, I was able to login to Teradata from cmd.

My code is using DBI connection with standard settings.

```
readRenviron("~/.Renviron")

databaseType <- "Teradata"
defaultDatabase <- "Test"

SERVER <- "tera2"
DATABASE <- "teradb"


driverList <- odbc::odbcListDrivers()
DRIVER <- as.character(subset(driverList, grepl(databaseType, driverList$name, ignore.case = TRUE))$name[1])
driverList <- odbc::odbcListDrivers()
DRIVER <- as.character(subset(driverList, grepl(databaseType, driverList$name, ignore.case = TRUE))$name[1])

queryData <- function(query) {

  con <- openConnection()

  queryDataRet <- data.frame(dbGetQuery(con, query))

  dbDisconnect(con)

  return(queryDataRet)

}


openConnection <- function() {

  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                   Driver = DRIVER,
                   Server = SERVER,
                   DBCName = DATABASE,
                   UID = Sys.getenv("tera_user"), 
                   PWD = Sys.getenv("tera_pass"))

  #Note: passwords are stored in .Renviron

  return(con)
}


testQuery <- function(){

  query <- paste0 ("select * from test")

  print(queryData(query))

}

testQuery()
```

When I change anything such as password or user it gives an error so I reckon my code is correct and the connection is caused somewhere outside.
Any ideas?

Comment: from the command line try this and see if you get a socket response: telnet tera2 1025

Comment: @access_granted How can I do it please?

Comment: just type "telnet tera2 1025"

Comment: @access_granted I am able to connect and pull data from Teradata with Command prompt and BTEQ. So, not sure if it is a firewall or something else in the code.

Comment: Not a firewall, otherwise you wouldn't be able to connect via bteq. Take a look at your odbc definition - it could be you are connecting to the wrong host.

Answer (score 0):

For Teradata ODBC driver, DBCName= is a network name (which for other drivers would typically supplied as Server=). The keyword for the default schema is Database=.

Try something like

```
  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
               Driver = DRIVER,
               DBCName = SERVER,
               Database = defaultDatabase,
               UID = Sys.getenv("tera_user"), 
               PWD = Sys.getenv("tera_pass"))
```

Comment: You might also look at using the [Teradata SQL Driver for R](https://github.com/Teradata/r-driver) instead of ODBC.

Comment: Does not work when I change DBCName to Database 'Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 08001: [Teradata][ODBC] (10380) Unable to establish connection with data source. Missing settings: {[DBCName]} ' and 'Error in find.package("teradatasql") : 
  there is no package called ‘teradatasql’'

Comment: The teradatasql package has to be installed manually with `install.packages` as documented if you want to use that instead of ODBC. When you connected successfully, did you use "tera2" or "teradb" (i.e. SERVER or DATABASE in the above script)?

Comment: It keeps saying that teradatasql is not for r 3.5.1

Comment: R 3.5.1 should be supported - though it needs to be 64-bit not 32-bit. To minimize confusion, let's focus on one of the connection methods, either *teradatasql* or *ODBC*.

Comment: @ Fred. Managed to install it however same error comes up. I tried dplyr.teradata as well. Nil luck. It seems that all codes are correct and something else plays the role.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all codes are correct and something else plays the role as several access routes return the same error.

Comment: "The same error" being the WSock32 HostUnreach? That could indicate a firewall or other network-related cause. How did you connect successfully "from cmd"?

Comment: I have used bteq and accessed and displayed data

Comment: And you are supplying the same value for DBCName (ODBC) or Host (teradatasql) as the "TDPID" (prior to the /username) that you used in the successful BTEQ .logon from the same client?

Comment: @ Fred, I use the same. Kept working on it will no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after many weeks I decided to have a look at .Renviron and I used `usethis::edit_r_environ()` to ensure all details are correct and it worked! Thanks all for all the support.